# HTML 5 Video player with custom button's are not working in Full Screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-video

I am creating a HTML 5 Video player with custom controls. I've referred the below url.

http://iandevlin.github.io/mdn/video-player/

Custom video player controls (Play, Pause, etc) were not working when the player in full screen in latest chrome and firefox browsers. Please help me to solve this.

Comment: What fullscreen mode? The one from these custom controls? It works for me on both latests FF and chrome. The original one from the video? That's normal: you need to request the fullscreen mode from the #videoContainer. If it bothers you some users might have access to this FS mode, you listen to the `<video>`'s fullscreenchange, prevent it, and trigger your custom one instead.

Comment: The buttons on full screen remains under video#video, so you're trying to click the video layout instead of clicking on the buttons. Use z-index to reach this

Comment: @JoelBonetR Thanks for your help. It's saved my day

Comment: =) let me add an answer to close the question

Answer (score 1):

The buttons on full screen remains under **video#video**, so you're trying to click the video layout instead of clicking on the buttons. Use z-index to reach this:

```
video#video{
    z-index: 1;
}
ul#video-controls{
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

This will move the buttons to the front, making it able for being clicked.